# Uniform convergence of $\sin(x^n)/x^n$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=\sin(x^n)/x^n$.
Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $1$ in the interval $(-\delta,\delta)- \{0\}$, with $0<\delta<1$.

So far what I've tried is to take the infinite norm of the function in the interval minus $1$ and see if its limit when $n$ tends to $\inf$ is equal to 0.

It looks like the function is strictly positive and less than 1 in the interval, plus it looks crecient in (-1,0) and decrecient in (0,1), though I haven't managed yet to formalize this.

Comment: You should change the intervall, since $\sin 1 \neq 1$.

Comment: How did you approach it thus far? Did you check the limits in the proper subsets?

Comment: @Martigan When taken to the limit, the function becomes non-continuous, so we don't really care that the value of sin1≠1

Comment: I might be missing something but it doesn't look like you have uniform convergence unless you assume the interval is $(-x_0,x_0)$ for some $0 < x_0 < 1$. For any $n$, and any $\epsilon > 0$, you can find a point $x$ close enough to 1 so that $|f_n(x) - 1| > \epsilon$.

Comment: Totally right. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another answer points out, this is false for your given interval $(-1,1)$. If you assume your interval is $(-\delta,\delta)$ for any $0 < \delta < 1$ then you will get uniform convergence, because $|x^n|$ will be no more than $\delta^n$ which tends to $0$ uniformly for all $x$ in your interval, and as soon as you have uniform convergence of $x^n$ to $0$ you can fairly easily show your sequence of functions converges uniformly to $1$. For your interval $(-1,1)$, $x^n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ and so the argument fails.

Comment: How do I fairly easily show the sequece of functions converges uniformly to 1?

Comment: @Jsevillamol For example you can use the fact that $\lim_{y \to 0} \sin(y) / y = 1$ and then as long as $x^n$ is small enough for all $x$, you will get as  close as you want to $1$ for all $x$ and $n \geq N$ for some $N$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Let $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin x^n}{x^n}$ and  take $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then  $|f_n(x_n)-1|\rightarrow 1-\frac{\sin (e^{-1})}{e^{-1}}\neq 0$ Therefore  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup\limits_{x\in (-1,1)\setminus \{0\}} |f_n(x)-1|>0$

Comment: But your $x_n$'s do not stay in a fixed $(-\delta,\delta )\setminus \{0\},$ with $0<\delta <1.$